# How to build in parallel with Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am trying to use the MsBuild api to run a build frpm C#. The following seems to work, but only runs the build single threaded. I really need this to run multi-threaded. When I run from the command line by running msbuild I can use the /m switch to start a parallel build. How can I achieve the same programmatically?

```
            var logger = new BasicLogger();

            var buildParameters = new BuildParameters()
            {
                Loggers = new List<Microsoft.Build.Framework.ILogger>() { logger },
                DetailedSummary = false,
                EnableNodeReuse = false,
                OnlyLogCriticalEvents = false,
                ShutdownInProcNodeOnBuildFinish = true
            };

            var globalProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Platform", platform },
                { "Configuration", configuration },
                { "BuildInParallel", "True" } // guessed at this, doesn't seem to have an effect
            };

            var targets = new string[] { target };

            var buildRequestData = new BuildRequestData(projectFileName, globalProperties, "15.0", targets, null);
            BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.ResetCaches();

            var buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(buildParameters, buildRequestData);
```

Comment: I've seen this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1cc8d5b5-9b27-4fa7-b053-fe77fb4cf087/ms-build-api-parallel-builds?forum=msbuild

Answer (score 1):

The API mechanism to specify that builds should be attempted in parallel when possible is [`BuildParameters.MaxNodeCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.execution.buildparameters.maxnodecount).

To mimic the default behavior of `msbuild.exe -m`, you might want to specify "as many processes as the machine has logical processors:

```cs
            var buildParameters = new BuildParameters()
            {
                Loggers = new List<Microsoft.Build.Framework.ILogger>() { logger },
                DetailedSummary = false,
                EnableNodeReuse = false,
                MaxNodeCount = System.Environment.ProcessorCount,
                OnlyLogCriticalEvents = false,
                ShutdownInProcNodeOnBuildFinish = true
            };
```